# Basic XML parsing in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [XML parsing using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987908/xml-parsing-using-jquery)

Let's say the XML file is this:

```
<blah>
 <test>This is a test</test>
</blah>
```

And let's say I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="example"></div>
```

How can I extract the contents of `test` from the XML file and make it the contents of `#example` in the HTML code with jQuery?

Also, let's say the XML file is hosted on a different domain than the HTML code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use JSON and jQuery's $.post (or $.ajax) rather than XML if you have the choice. It'll save you some headaches, IMO. Mind you, it's a disputed issue - some basic discussion of the choice is found [here](http://www.jquery4u.com/json/json-vs-xml/).

The basic form I use is as follows:

```
var namevariable="Suzie", agevariable=43;
var dS=JSON.stringify({"name":namevariable,"age":agevariable});
$.post('destination.php',{data:dS},function (res){
  var o=JSON.parse(res);
  // Return JSON format:  {"unit":"13","subject":"English"}  
  $("#example").html(o.subject);
},"text");  // closing argument of $.post
```

This sends the name and age fields to destination.php. It then expects destination.php to return a unit and subject variable. The subject variable is then put into your `<div id='example'></div>`.

There's heaps of help on this site and the net if you choose to use this method.

You can, for example, check the format of your JSON data using [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "jsonp xml",
  url: "http://mydomain.com/xmlfile.xml",
}).done(function(data) { 
  $('#example').append($(data).find('test').text());
});
```