# jQuery .load() not working in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

`.load()` was working fine, but for some reason it's not in Chrome now (presumably some kind of update). I'm on Chrome 5.0.375.55. I've isolated the problem to this:

### index.htm

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
          $('#reader').load('test.htm');
      });
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='reader'>Loading ...</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

### test.htm

```
<h1>Loaded successfully</h1>
```

This works on Firefox and IE, but on Chrome it replaces the contents of the `#reader` div with nothing.

**Edit:** I should add that I'm running this locally, and it's never going to be deployed on a web server.

**Edit2:** I've tried `.load('file:///C:/path/to/test.htm')` which works in FF but not Chrome.

Comment: have you tried specifying the exact path?

Comment: just for grins, try putting the full URL, http and all to the test page. I had a similar problem just last week, and full URL fixed it.

Comment: @Will and Neil: thanks, but see my edits.

Comment: @Skilldrick - What happens if you launch chrome with `--disable-web-security`?

Comment: Apparently Chrome has issues with files hosted from the file system, and the Same Origin Policy. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541949/problems-with-jquery-getjson-using-local-files-in-chrome

Comment: @patrick Thanks, that's the badger.

Comment: I Have hosted on Local iis configured and .load() works perfectly

Comment: I have the same issue but --allow-file-access-from-files didn't work for me.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's the "same origin policy" as interpreted by Chrome (or a bug with the same effect). Try running Chrome with `--allow-file-access-from-files`.

Comment: Thank god for Stack Overflow :) Thanks a lot, that solved it. This is a pain though, because my app will be distributed on CD, so it just won't work on Chrome. I hope they fix it soon!

Comment: You can follow their progress on the issue here: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=40787

Answer (score 4):

I've the same problem, but you may find it works if you upload it to a web server. I've tested it and it done when i upload test page to server.

Answer (score 2):

Neither `--disable-web-security` nor `--allow-file-access-from-files` worked for me, although I found that using '127.0.0.1' instead of 'localhost' solved the problem.