# JQuery Load() Error In Loading A Txt File

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can not seem to get the jQuery load function to work.

My HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="Jquery_script.js"></script>

<script>$(document).ready(function(){ladda(); });</script>
</head>

<body>

<form namne="load">
<fieldset>
    <legend>load</legend>
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td><div id="L1"><h1>vill du ändra denna text</h1></div></td>
        </tr>
         </table>
    <button id="load_text">ändra</button>
</fieldset>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

the problem is that the load button does not load external content

the javascript file:

```
(function($){
    ladda = function() {
    $("#load_text").click(function(){
            $("#L1").load("innehall.txt", function() {
                alert('Load was performed.');
            });
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

and the external .txt file only

```
<h2>du har ändrat innehållet</h2>
<p>detta är det nya innehållet</p>
```

Please help my figure out why the .txt file not is replacing the div id="L1" tag when pressing the button "ändra".

Comment: Can you see any AJAX errors in your console?

Comment: Is the path to innehall.txt correct? Look in your developer console to see if there are any errors reported.

Comment: Have you tried walking through your code in a debugger like the Chrome Dev Tools?

Comment: Maybe you could give some more details about how the problem is occurring? E.g.: Are there any error messages, is the load() function being executed, is the callback for the .load() function being executed, etc.

Comment: I tried out your code in my browser and it works perfectly, Please do check if the file "innehall.txt" is in the same folder..

Comment: how do i check the console?

Comment: Hej Josef, to view the console just press F12.

Comment: Also, view the network tab in the console. Read more about the chrome console here: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console

Comment: alert is presented when pressing the button but the content is not updated

Comment: there's no error message in the console

Answer (score 0):

Check path to your file and note: Chrome (if you use that browser) not allows local XHR requests (you can't use less.js with local .less files, for example).

Comment: If you write .load('filename.txt') file must be located in same directory as your html file. Also, which browser you using?

Comment: it's in the same directory and i have tried it in safari and chrome

Comment: Try to open developer toolbar in Chrome (press F12), go to Console tab and refresh your page. Post here errors, if it has.

Comment: Also, read that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990518/jquery-load-not-working-in-chrome page for more explanation.