# jquery load function not working in chrome which is working in firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

im working with jquery load function which require to fill content of a div from page to another page.

first.html

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
   <script>
 $('#getselect').find('option:selected').text();
 </script>
 </head>
<body>
<div id="getdiv">Not loaded yet.</div>
</body>
 </html>
```

second.html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <b>Footer navigation:</b>
  <div id="getit"></div>
   <div id="getitselected"></div>
   <script>
  $("#getit").load("first.html #getdiv");
  </script>
  </body>
 </html>
```

The script works fine in firefox but not working in chrom. please help me.

Comment: Remove all html, head, body tag in first.html.

Comment: Are you assuming the jQuery code in the first file will set the select in the second file ?

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping your code in `$(document).ready()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#getit").load("first.html #getdiv");
});
```

Comment: Why would that help ?

Comment: @kevin bowersox i tried it but didnot work!

Comment: This would only of made a difference if the code was not already at the bottom of the body (and is therefore already executed when the DOM is ready).

Answer (score 1):

If you do not host your site on a server and you just try to open an .html file from a browser, in that case chrome cannot access another file in your filesystem. 
You have to deploy your project to a server e.g wamp and test it. You' ll see chrome works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is an AJAX request and chrome won't run it if you try to directly access first.html from second.html because of `same-origin-policy`

Put it on a `server` (local/non-local) and try to run it like localhost:3000/testProject/second.html , it'll work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can start Chrome like this

```
cd C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application
start chrome.exe C:\second.html --disable-web-security
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `preventdefault()`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   event.preventDefault();
   $("#getit").load("first.html #getdiv");
});
```

Comment: Would be nice to explain why this would make a difference.

Comment: -1: Who upvoted this? This is complete nonsense. `preventDefault()` is not applicable to the DOM ready event (and `event` does not exist in the scope of your code *even if it did do anything*). :(

Comment: yes you are right, but it's work done for this situation. and it's useful for someone that upvote this.

Comment: @Ali.azimi not a working solution..

Answer (score 0):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2990622/1123295 and http://www.chrome-allow-file-access-from-file.com/

You will need to run chrome with --allow-file-access-from-files to get jquery's load function to work locally.

If in Windows 7+, pin Chrome to your taskbar and right click on the icon, then right click on "Google Chrome" and select Properties. Then change the target to have the new flag, something like this:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --allow-file-access-from-files

Now every time chrome launches, it will use the new policy.

Comment: I am having the same issue as OP, this didn't fix it