# Javascript code for common Header Footer not working in Chrome Browser

Tags: javascript, html

I have used the common header and footer for my website.

The javascript code I have used for it. It works in Firefox but not in Chrome.

The javascript code is

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#header").load("header.html"); 
    $("#footer").load("footer.html"); 
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery .load() not working in Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990518/jquery-load-not-working-in-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

A similar question was posted a few years ago:
[jQuery .load() not working in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990518/jquery-load-not-working-in-chrome)

To summarize the solution, try running Chrome with

> --allow-file-access-from-files

Comment: "--allow-file-access-from-files" This is not working for crome