# jquery-include  example that works with Firefox does not work with Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

None of my uses of [jquery-include](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-include/) have worked with Chrome which has been
during the last few months.

Contents of `x.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.include-2.3.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Contents of stuff.html: <span src="stuff.html"></span>.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Contents of `stuff.html`:

```
STUFF
```

For `x.html` the result is as expected with Firefox:

> Contents of stuff.html: STUFF .

whereas with Chrome the result is missing the contents of `stuff.html`:

> Contents of stuff.html: .

The current version used with this test is:

> Google Chome  10.0.648.82 beta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurs when you use [jquery-include](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-include/) in the local file system `file:` with versions of Chrome released in the last year.

It's due to a change in Access-Control restrictions in the local filesystem which was made to address valid security risks. You can overide this behaviour by starting Crome from the command line with the `--allow-file-access-from-files` flag. Judging by the lengthy discussion on Chromium issues [here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=47416) and [here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=4197) this is unlikely to be resolved.

Using jquery-include with Chrome over http is not affected.

See also [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208530/xmlhttprequest-origin-null-is-not-allowed-access-control-access-allow-for-file).