# Error: "Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin" when loading an XML file with JQuery's ajax method

Tags: jquery, xml

This is my code:

```
this.loadMap = function () {
    this._map = null;
    this._width = 0;
    this._height = 0;
    this._playerX = 0;
    this._playerY = 0;
    this.finished = false;
    this.loaded = false;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "maze1.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: this.parseXmlMap,
        context: this
    });
};
```

The error i'm getting is

> "XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   file:///C:/wamp/www/mazegame/maze1.xml.
>   Origin null is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin".

This same script works fine in Firefox

Comment: possible duplicate of [XMLHttpRequest Origin null is not allowed Access-Control-Allow-Origin for file:/// to file:/// (Serverless)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208530/xmlhttprequest-origin-null-is-not-allowed-access-control-allow-origin-for-file)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You're testing this in Chrome? What's basically happening is because you're loading the file from your filesystem instead of from a server, Chrome is setting your origin to `null` even though the resource you're requesting is local to you. If you were to do this from an HTTP server such as Apache, I think it would work just fine.

Comment: Yes I'm using Chrome, but I've the Apache server runnning as well

Comment: Sorry, you were right, I have the server up, but I didint realize that I wasnt accesing the web pasge through it...

Answer (score 19):

Yes, Google in their blessed wisdom decided that Chrome will not permit an access to local files for rather obscure security reasons. Every two local files are considered as if they were from different domains, and accessing a local file is considered a cross-site request.

There is a workaround, but useful only in some situations: If you can run Chrome with a command line parameter `--allow-file-access-from-files`, the security check will not be done.

Comment: Its a rather obvious security reason. Allowing local files to be accessed via AJAX would allow any website to probe your computer.

Comment: @RobertHurst except that the origin is also a local file, so it's not "any web site" accessing the files (it's me!) :)

Answer (score 6):

I had this same issue with Chrome (Version 20.0.1132.57) and using --allow-file-access-from-files didn't work for me (on Ubuntu 12.04).

But, using the command `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` in the directory that holds the localfiles I'm trying to test with allows me to work around the problem.  That command launches an HTTP server that serves the current directory tree at `http://localhost:8000/`

So, if I have a file test.html that uses an ajax call for a file in the same dir I can use `http://localhost:8000/test.html` and Chrome will be ok with it.  For me, this is fine for local dev/testing.

I came across that command on [www.commandlinefu.com](http://www.commandlinefu.com).

Answer (score 5):

Just to reiterate what Paul & Juggernaut said:

In OSX open terminal and paste this command

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --allow-file-access-from-files
```

Answer (score 1):

You try to access both web page and resources file as file route file:///

You can do following in OSX

```
open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app --args --allow-file-access-from-files
```

try to request web page with local server (http://localhost/your_website.html)

read more about cross site and iFrame at
http://weblog.bocoup.com/third-party-javascript-development-future/