# AJAX GET not working with local JSON file?

Tags: jquery, ajax, local-files

I had a JSONP URL, that was pulling data and just switched to a local JSON file and now I am getting errors.  I don't understand why it is not working with a local JSON file?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        dataType : 'json',
        url: '/json/topics.json',
        success : function(data) {
            console.log(data); 
            var topics = [];
            $.each(data.results, function(index, obj){
                topics.push({
                    username: obj.TopicName,
                    mentions: obj.LastHourCount,
                    totalcount: obj.TotalCount,
                    daycount: obj.Last24HoursCount
                }); 
            });
            $('#leader').tmpl(topics).appendTo('#top3');
        } 
    });
</script>
```

In the console it is saying AJAX is a anonymous function for some reason?
Any suggestions?

Comment: what about `url: 'json/topics.json'`

Comment: if i use that url i get this error: XMLHttpRequest cannot load

Comment: You have the jquery core file loaded correctly?

Comment: What is the url of this script?

Comment: I'm just using the google jquery url: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: @Xtian -- I don't think this would cause your issue, but don't use a semi colon between attributes in your script tag. ref: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_whereto.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$.ajax` is asynchronous and it looks like you are trying to change the DOM on page load, add

```
async: false,
```

to your `$.ajax` parameters. Note that it may slow down page load.

Example:

```
 $.ajax({
    type : 'GET',
    dataType : 'json',
    async: false,
    // rest of your code
```

See this post if you are using local files, not through webserver, and getting a `Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin` error:

[Error: "Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin" when loading an XML file with JQuery's ajax method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396527/error-origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin-when-loading)

Comment: after adding that i get this error: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///json/topics.json?_=1327938971630. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: @Xtian check the path to your `topics.json` file. Seems like the issue is there now.

Comment: @Xtian This post might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396527/error-origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin-when-loading

Comment: I put it up on a server to make sure this wasn't the issue. The console is outputting the data, but then I get the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: @Xtian Sounds like your question was answered and now you have an issue with the data returned. I can't see the data so it's very hard to troubleshoot this issue. You said it was jsonp and now it's json so take a look at the data and make sure it is in the correct format for how you are attempting to read it.

Comment: +1: 1 yr after this was posted, i find it to be a life saver! :)