# Ajax Get request will not find JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

I have a JSON file that I am trying to pull Key and Values from but this function will not ever succeed. The 'datafile.json' is in the exact same directory. The alert(weblink) never runs but the alert('test 1') works fine.

```
<div class="container"> 
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" align="center">
        <col width="50%">
        <col>
        <col width="15%">
        <col width="25%">
        <thead>
            <tr bgcolor="#76767a" align="right">
                <th align="left">Skill</th>
                <th>Rank</th>
                <th>Level</th>
                <th>Experience</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>

<script>
var weblink = 'datafile.json';
var data = {};
$(document).ready(function(){   
    alert('test 1');    
    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        dataType : 'json',
        url : weblink,
        success: function(data){
            alert(weblink);
            $.each(datas, function(key, val){
            items.push("<tr>");
            items.push("<td id =''"+key+"''>"+val.skill+"</td>");
            items.push("<td id =''"+key+"''>"+val.rank+"</td>");
            items.push("<td id =''"+key+"''>"+val.level+"</td>");
            items.push("<td id =''"+key+"''>"+val.exp+"</td>");
            items.push("</tr>");
            });
            $("<tbody/>", {"class": "mydata", html: items.join("")}).appendTo("table");
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

My datafile.json is:

```
[
{
"Skill": "Overall",
"Rank": "1132673",
"Level": "420",
"Exp": "466345"
},
{
"Skill": "Attack",
"Rank": "1256428",
"Level": "23",
"Exp": "6563"
},
{
"Skill": "Defence",
"Rank": "1182611",
"Level": "28",
"Exp": "11069"
},
{
"Skill": "Strength",
"Rank": "1250418",
"Level": "22",
"Exp": "6238"
},
{
"Skill": "Constitution",
"Rank": "1292788",
"Level": "27",
"Exp": "10413"
},
{
"Skill": "Ranged",
"Rank": "0",
"Level": "1",
"Exp": "0"
},
{
"Skill": "Prayer",
"Rank": "1116462",
"Level": "20",
"Exp": "4611"
},
{
"Skill": "Magic",
"Rank": "1058028",
"Level": "32",
"Exp": "18183"
},
{
"Skill": "Cooking",
"Rank": "0",
"Level": "1",
"Exp": "0"
},
{
"Skill": "Woodcutting",
"Rank": "955909",
"Level": "47",
"Exp": "79651"
},
{
"Skill": "Fletching",
"Rank": "0",
"Level": "1",
"Exp": "0"
},
{
"Skill": "Fishing",
"Rank": "0",
"Level": "1",
"Exp": "0"
},
{
"Skill": "Firemaking",
"Rank": "668820",
"Level": "58",
"Exp": "245606"
},
{
"Skill": "Crafting",
"Rank": "1060629",
"Level": "16",
"Exp": "3090"
},
{
"Skill": "Smithing",
"Rank": "956265",
"Level": "35",
"Exp": "24400"
},
{
"Skill": "Mining",
"Rank": "0",
"Level": "1",
"Exp": "0"
},
{
"Skill": "Herblore",
"Rank": "0",
"Level": "1",
"Exp": "0"
},
{
"Skill": "Agility",
"Rank": "0",
"Level": "1",
"Exp": "0"
},
{
"Skill": "Thieving",
"Rank": "0",
"Level": "1",
"Exp": "0"
},
{
"Skill": "Slayer",
"Rank": "0",
"Level": "1",
"Exp": "0"
},
{
"Skill": "Farming",
"Rank": "0",
"Level": "1",
"Exp": "0"
},
{
"Skill": "Runecrafting",
"Rank": "619807",
"Level": "42",
"Exp": "49314"
},
{
"Skill": "Hunter",
"Rank": "0",
"Level": "1",
"Exp": "0"
},
{
"Skill": "Construction",
"Rank": "0",
"Level": "1",
"Exp": "0"
},
{
"Skill": "Summoning",
"Rank": "0",
"Level": "1",
"Exp": "0"
},
{
"Skill": "Dungeoneering",
"Rank": "0",
"Level": "1",
"Exp": "0"
},
{
"Skill": "Divination",
"Rank": "0",
"Level": "1",
"Exp": "0"
},
{
"Skill": "Invention",
"Rank": "0",
"Level": "1",
"Exp": "0"
}
]
```

Comment: if you are not using a http server, and you are using chrome, this will not work ... solution: use a http server

Comment: all of this is located on my server. My webpage loads fine but cannot access the JSON in the same directory.

Comment: Typo. datas !== data

Comment: Check your developer tools console for errors

Comment: Try to change weblink address to "./datafile.json" and see the results

Comment: Maybe this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9066335/ajax-get-not-working-with-local-json-file

Comment: No errors Jaromanda and datas i changed but made no difference

Comment: Did you Try to browse the file url directly in the browser? Does it return the file successfully there? Put an error handler block `error:` in your Ajax block and see if there is any error such as 404,400 or 500. Debugging is the only way to figure out the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load json files using script tags.  Optionally give it a .js extension.  You would have to assign it to a variable, and it will be treated like javascript, but maybe that works for you.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="datafile.json"></script>
<div class="container"> 
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" align="center">
        <col width="50%">
        <col>
        <col width="15%">
        <col width="25%">
        <thead>
            <tr bgcolor="#76767a" align="right">
                <th align="left">Skill</th>
                <th>Rank</th>
                <th>Level</th>
                <th>Experience</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>

<script>
// var data is defined in the json script
$(window).load(function(){   
  $.each(data, function(skill) {
      items.push("<tr>");
      $.each(skill, function(key, val){
          items.push("<td id =''"+key+"''>"+val.skill+"</td>");
          items.push("<td id =''"+key+"''>"+val.rank+"</td>");
          items.push("<td id =''"+key+"''>"+val.level+"</td>");
          items.push("<td id =''"+key+"''>"+val.exp+"</td>");
      });
      items.push("</tr>");
  })

  $("<tbody/>", {"class": "mydata", html: items.join("")}).appendTo("table");
});

</script>
```

**datafile.json**

```
var data =
[
{
"Skill": "Overall",
"Rank": "1132673",
"Level": "420",
"Exp": "466345"
},
{
"Skill": "Attack",
"Rank": "1256428",
"Level": "23",
"Exp": "6563"
},
{
"Skill": "Defence",
"Rank": "1182611",
"Level": "28",
"Exp": "11069"
},
{
"Skill": "Strength",
"Rank": "1250418",
"Level": "22",
"Exp": "6238"
},
{
"Skill": "Constitution",
"Rank": "1292788",
"Level": "27",
"Exp": "10413"
},
{
"Skill": "Ranged",
"Rank": "0",
"Level": "1",
"Exp": "0"
},
{
"Skill": "Prayer",
"Rank": "1116462",
"Level": "20",
"Exp": "4611"
},
{
"Skill": "Magic",
"Rank": "1058028",
"Level": "32",
"Exp": "18183"
},
{
"Skill": "Cooking",
"Rank": "0",
"Level": "1",
"Exp": "0"
},
{
"Skill": "Woodcutting",
"Rank": "955909",
"Level": "47",
"Exp": "79651"
},
{
"Skill": "Fletching",
"Rank": "0",
"Level": "1",
"Exp": "0"
},
{
"Skill": "Fishing",
"Rank": "0",
"Level": "1",
"Exp": "0"
},
{
"Skill": "Firemaking",
"Rank": "668820",
"Level": "58",
"Exp": "245606"
},
{
"Skill": "Crafting",
"Rank": "1060629",
"Level": "16",
"Exp": "3090"
},
{
"Skill": "Smithing",
"Rank": "956265",
"Level": "35",
"Exp": "24400"
},
{
"Skill": "Mining",
"Rank": "0",
"Level": "1",
"Exp": "0"
},
{
"Skill": "Herblore",
"Rank": "0",
"Level": "1",
"Exp": "0"
},
{
"Skill": "Agility",
"Rank": "0",
"Level": "1",
"Exp": "0"
},
{
"Skill": "Thieving",
"Rank": "0",
"Level": "1",
"Exp": "0"
},
{
"Skill": "Slayer",
"Rank": "0",
"Level": "1",
"Exp": "0"
},
{
"Skill": "Farming",
"Rank": "0",
"Level": "1",
"Exp": "0"
},
{
"Skill": "Runecrafting",
"Rank": "619807",
"Level": "42",
"Exp": "49314"
},
{
"Skill": "Hunter",
"Rank": "0",
"Level": "1",
"Exp": "0"
},
{
"Skill": "Construction",
"Rank": "0",
"Level": "1",
"Exp": "0"
},
{
"Skill": "Summoning",
"Rank": "0",
"Level": "1",
"Exp": "0"
},
{
"Skill": "Dungeoneering",
"Rank": "0",
"Level": "1",
"Exp": "0"
},
{
"Skill": "Divination",
"Rank": "0",
"Level": "1",
"Exp": "0"
},
{
"Skill": "Invention",
"Rank": "0",
"Level": "1",
"Exp": "0"
}
];
```

Comment: Didnt help anything. Before I added this code the datafile.json would not even show up in Sources via the developer tools. Now it does but still no success from function.

Comment: you would no longer need the ajax, you can directly use the variable, ill edit answer

Comment: Okay. I will watch for it. Thanks.

Comment: Okay that worked up until I get an error stating that 'data' is not defined. (index):52 Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined and i did alter the JSON file

Comment: ah yea, document.ready fires when the DOM is loaded not when assets are loaded.  You want $(window).load() . bc that will fire AFTER the json file has been loaded and the data var defined.  I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you soooo much! it populated the table!!!! I just now have to figure out why all values are returning as undefined.

Comment: your loop assumes an object and has forgotten these are all nested in an array.  I will update again :)

Comment: two caveats, first json is almost a javascript object literal (just no types like Date), so you might as well go ahead and make it be a .js file.  If you want this data to be dynamic, you will either have to write to this .js file and make sure you set an appropriate cache strategy (so browsers will use the fresh version) or look into a small http server, possibly nodejs, and go back to ajax.  Two, global variables are not so great, that is what we have done here by saying var data = ... in the json file.  You should wrap this in a function or module to prevent global namespace cluttering.