# Why Dijit doesn't work for me?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dojo

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7.1/dojo/dojo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7.1/dojo/resources/dojo.css"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7.1/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        dojo.require("dijit.layout.AccordionContainer");
    </script>

    <script type="text/css">
        html, body {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body class='claro'>
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.AccordionContainer" style="width: 200px; height: 95%; margin: 0 auto;">
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.AccordionPane" title="pane #1">accordion pane #1</div>
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.AccordionPane" title="pane #2">accordion pane #2</div>
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.AccordionPane" title="pane #3">accordion pane #3</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It is just a very simple code from the example of Dojo.

When I run it in safari, nothing appears but some plain text.

When I run it in chrome, following error occurs:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7.1/dijit/layout/AccordionContainer.js. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

and

```
Uncaught Error: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101              dojo.js:15
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396527/error-origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin-when-loading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.You forgot to require dijit.layout.AccordionPane
2. You forgot to invoke the parser

Try this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var dojoConfig = {
                                    async : true,
                                    parseOnLoad : true
                            }
        </script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7.1/dojo/dojo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7.1/dojo/resources/dojo.css"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7.1/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">

        <script type="text/javascript">
            require(["dijit/layout/AccordionContainer", 
                     "dijit/layout/AccordionPane"], 
                     function(){
                          // your code...
                     }
            );
        </script>

        <script type="text/css">
            html, body {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body class='claro'>
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.AccordionContainer" style="width: 200px; height: 95%; margin: 0 auto;">
            <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.AccordionPane" title="pane #1">accordion pane #1</div>
            <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.AccordionPane" title="pane #2">accordion pane #2</div>
            <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.AccordionPane" title="pane #3">accordion pane #3</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Alternatively, instead of invoking the parser manually, you may invoke it on page load by adding  data-dojo-config="parseOnLoad: true" to the script tag where dojo.js is loaded, or by setting the variable dojoConfig before dojo.js is loaded (see http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.7/dojo_config/).

Comment: I have copy all of your code and run, it's doesn't work. It's have some error.

Comment: Try the new version... I replaced the manual parsing by setting parseOnLoad=true and making the module loader async.