# after including jquery-mobile.js links are not re direction

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink

here is my question

I have included "jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js" in to my website but after adding that all normal links are not re directing to corresponding pages.

I am attaching screen shots here

[image]

Comment: See if this post answers your question. It looks like it could be the same problem [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396527/error-origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin-when-loading)

Answer (score 0):

Have you add  data-ajax="false" or  rel="external" to all of your links?

See JQM doc here...http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/widgets/links/