# How to read XML file in IE by javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I have a question about reading the XML in IE using javascript. I have the following javascript, it should read an XML file. However, I can only read the XML file in FireFox but not IE. Can anyone help me?

It shows 'Access is denied'

```
function loadXMLDoc(location) {  // location = './abc/abc.xml'
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)   {
        xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else  {
        xhttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xhttp.open("GET",location,false);  // IE mention the error in here
    xhttp.send();
    return xhttp.responseXML;
}
```

p.s I found the example in here 'http://www.w3schools.com/dom/tryit.asp?filename=try_dom_loadxml'

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are not using a fully qualified URL. Try this:

```
var location = 'http://yoursite.com/abc/abc.xml';
```

The way you are writing it, IE is probably thinking this is a local file, not on the server.

**Edit:** If you want to load a local file, then try this:

```
var location = 'file:///path/to/abc/abc.xml'; // linux
```

or

```
var location = 'C:/path/to/abc/abc.xml'; // windows (I think?)
```

If you are still getting problems with IE, it's probably to do with IE's security settings. Turn these off or to "low" or whatever and try again.

**Edit 2:** According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208530/xmlhttprequest-origin-null-is-not-allowed-access-control-access-allow-for-file/4276931#4276931), Chrome browser will not allow ajax requests to file:/// resources deeming local requests to conflict with the same-origin policy. I guess IE implements the same constraint. There is no workaround, so: you'll need to run a server on your localhost. (However yes Firefox *does* allow these requests.)

Comment: I am testing the code in my local machins, could you please to teach me how to do that? my file in the desktop.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I found that it is still not work, I have updated the question which post a link to w3c, would you mind to take a look?

Comment: @John: what is the URL of the page in your browser? Is it "http://localhost/yourpage.html' or is it a file path like "C:/path/to/yourpage.html'?

Comment: thank you for your reply. The path is 'C:/John/Desktop/abc.xml'

Comment: @John: no I mean the path of the actual html page in your browser address bar

Comment: it is 'file:///C:/John/Desktop/File_A/File_B/test.html'

Comment: ok for the location try: var location = 'file:///C:/John/Desktop/abc.xml';

Comment: thank you for your reply. But it is the same case, it always shows the 'Access is denied.' and show the js file and line number, Code 0 and Char:2, any hits in the Code:0 and Char 2?