# Paper.js giving error in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, paperjs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [XMLHttpRequest Origin null is not allowed Access-Control-Access-Allow for file:/// to file:/// (Serverless)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208530/xmlhttprequest-origin-null-is-not-allowed-access-control-access-allow-for-file)

I am getting this error in Google chrome when I use paper.js.
Even if I remove All my code from my js file, then also it gives error.
Just started with paperjs, so not getting what is wrong

Uncaught Error: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101

after having some small code in demo.js file one more error comes:
 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///E:/Shruti/Remote%20Triggering/demo/js/demo.js. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.

Comment: You cannot load a local file using XHRs

Answer (score -2):

You should add `--allow-file-access-from-files` option to chrome if you want to work offline.