# jQuery .load() to load dynamic page in div tag

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to load a html page in a div through `.load()` method.

```
<div id="randomDiv">
```

and then in Js function ( let say on click of a button ) trying this : `$('#randomDiv').load('js/abc.html');`

I have added `"script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" "` in the html file.

But i am getting this error `: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:////C:/code/js/abc.html Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

I am using Chrome.

Also i am getting the warning at page load for almost all js included "Resource interpreted as Script but transfered with MIME type text/plain".

What is going wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to use

```
$('#randomDiv').load('js/abc.html');
```

This is a cross-domain request and is not permitted. Test from **localhost** instead of an **external file**

your `abc.html` should be inside localhost

Comment: I am using # only. What cross-domain request is not permitted , i didnt understand this.My default.html is at C:/code/default.html and the default.js containing the load code is at C:/code/js/default.js .

Comment: you are welcome , mark the answer as the correct one please , so the future users can easily find the correct solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is wrong as already mentioned, but you're also trying to make an ajax request to a local file which is not permitted per default. You should run your page on a web server, but you could also switch file access on with `chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files`.

See this question for more info [XMLHttpRequest Origin null is not allowed Access-Control-Allow-Origin for file:/// to file:/// (Serverless)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208530/xmlhttprequest-origin-null-is-not-allowed-access-control-access-allow-for-file)

Comment: Thanks , I used localhost and it works . Somehow changing the chrome setting didn't work.