# How to style Blogger gadget with iframe and own head with styles

Tags: css, iframe, blogger

I have a Blogger test blog with one Widget, and I'm using one of blogger's templates:
http://dareshtest.blogspot.com/

I'm trying to style the contents of the gadget to match the rest of the site, but nothing seems to work (adding specific styles to the template, making them important...)

How to target that gadget and style it correctly?

Comment: Please refer to this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe)

Comment: I Tried my answer on my computer and I also was not able to make it work, so I modified the code similar to http://javascript.info/tutorial/frames-and-iframes but Chrome was giving me this error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208530/xmlhttprequest-origin-null-is-not-allowed-access-control-access-allow-for-file. So I deleted my answer. You could try to ask your question at http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you switch to your HTML at the top you can see that you have all of your Widgets listed. If you jump to them, you can see that each one has its own ID. To style a specific widget just use the ID and add your CSS.