# jQuery update span from .get() error

Tags: jquery, html

Hi there I'm still quite new with jQuery. I have a html file which contains a span that I would like to fetch and populate from a file on server. Here is my HTML file:

```
<div class="home-page main">
<section class="grid-wrap" >
    <header class="grid col-full">
    <hr></hr>
        <p class="fleft">首頁</p>
    </header>

    <div class="grid col-one-half mq2-col-full">
        <span class="Welcome_Message"></span>
    </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Then here is my jQuery script file:

```
$.get('texts/Welcome_Message.txt', function(data) {
    $('.grid span').html(data);
}).done(function() { alert("success"); })
  .fail(function() { alert("error"); });
```

I've tried with the preview in DreamWeaver and it will populate and show the `alert("success");` message properly. However running it in a browser (no matter which one) shows the `alert("error");` and the span is not populated. Anyone can help please?

Comment: What is your network debugging tool showing ? Any 404 / Javascript error ? (Chrome's / Firefox one)

Comment: hi there, i don't use any debugging tool. would you recommend one to me?

Answer (score 0):

I think you simply need to load the data into the (.Welcome_Message) straight away. though i don't know why you need the response

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('span.Welcome_Message').load("texts/Welcome_Message.txt");
   });
</script> Also check this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208530/xmlhttprequest-origin-null-is-not-allowed-access-control-access-allow-for-file/
```

Comment: thank you for answering, however in fact the function is **already** in the $(document).ready() event...

Comment: Okay then simply pop in that line $('span.Welcome_Message').load("texts/Welcome_Message.txt");

Comment: I've tried it buddy... yet it is still only showing in dreamweaver... not inside a browser

Comment: okay create new page add this to the top <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script> then in the body type this line <script>
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('span.Welcome_Message').load("texts/Welcome_Message.txt");
   });
</script> open in a browser

Comment: nothing had changed... still showing in dreamweaver but not in browser... thank you for actively trying to help me out btw =]

Comment: what type of browser are you using

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31292/discussion-between-matthew-and-shapcyber)

Comment: Try changing the extension from Welcome_Message.txt to Welcome_Message.html