# angularjs looking for files on localhost after grunt-distribution

Tags: ajax, gruntjs

i'm working on a project with angular and grunt. before "grunting" angular reads the local files, but after "grunting" my index.html-file doesn't show anything. the tool "console" in chrome show me this error message:

"**XMLHttpRequest cannot load** file:///Users/userxx/Dropbox/Produktion/_resources/workspaces/userxx.html5/taleshipkiosk/_temp/repository/taleshipkiosk/dist/views/kiosk.html. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. index.html:1"

its seems that angular is still looking for one local file called "kiosk.html". but how can that be? this file (kiosk.html) is already in my dist-folder.

any ideas how to fix it?

thx

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look like it's really related to grunt at all. It seems like you're trying to make an XHR request that Chrome is regarding as cross-origin. You should try looking for answers regarding "origin null not allowed"

example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4752452/628699