# cant get jquery autocomplete to read in js file of data

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

Using JQuery UI widget to try and call in this js file of string data but getting 'no results found'. No console errors. I simply don't think I'm referencing this correctly as I'm not very proficient with jquery/js. If someone could point me in a direction, I'd appreciate it.

```
<input type="text" id="test" />
```

scripts

```
<script src='js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js'></script>
<script src="js/autocomplete/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="js/Providers.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

formatted in file

```
var providerdata=[{"ProviderID":"1","NAME":"name1"},{"ProviderID":"2","NAME":"name2"},{"ProviderID":"3","NAME":"name3"}];
```

calling

```
$('#test').autocomplete({
    source: providerdata,
    success: function(data) {
            var cat_data = $.map(data.Providers, function(item) {
                return {
                    value: item.NAME,
                    label: item.NAME,
                };
            });
            $("#test").autocomplete({
                minlength:3,
                delay: 500,
                source: cat_data               
            });
        }
});
```

Comment: Did you read the doc before posting here ? http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uhm... i'm not sure, but i don't think that autocomplete has `success` property because its a property of an ajax call... maybe you use it inside an ajax call to get back the source, but in your case you already has surce `providerdata`, true?

Assuming that your `$.map` works fine, you can do something like:

```
var cat_data = $.map(providerdata, function(item) {
      return {
        value: item.NAME,
        label: item.NAME,
      }
});

$('#test').autocomplete({
    source: cat_data,
    minlength:3,
    delay: 500,
});
```

[edit] - i see doc and i think you can do also:

```
$('#test').autocomplete({
    source: function(){
        return $.map(providerdata, function(item) {
            return {
                 value: item.NAME,
                 label: item.NAME,
            };
        })
    },
    minlength:3,
    delay: 500,
});
```

is it works?

Comment: Thanks, that's all I needed. I figured it was too much as I got it to work from a json file calling with ajax but was gettting this error.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208530/xmlhttprequest-origin-null-is-not-allowed-access-control-access-allow-for-file But I hardly code with js/jquery so I dont know this stuff. thanks!

Comment: my english is bad and i don't understand all your comment. But if you solved your problem and i helped you... let's rock mate!