# no access-control-allow-origin header is present same folder

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, html

I know this question has been asked many times and it is due to same-origin policy however My files are normal .html files on my computer hard drive on the same folder and I still get this error!

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#some").load("include.html");
        });
</script>
```

And include.html only has one `<p>` tag which contains some text. I have downloaded jQuery and  included it! I can run other scripts but this one causes the following error:

```
    Failed to load resource: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.        file:///C:/Users/MYUSER/Documents/code/include.html
    XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/MYUSER/Documents/code/include.html. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

As you can see they are in the same folder but I still get this error. I user Chrome as browser!

`some` is the `id` of the div tag in the body of my page.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208530/xmlhttprequest-origin-null-is-not-allowed-access-control-access-allow-for-file

Comment: But other jQuery scripts run file on my file system. Is it just AJAX scripts that cannot run file system?

Comment: @Arijoon: That's what I meant.

Comment: Ok thanks. If you place that as an answer I can accept it and close this question.