# GoLang: Setting header to null for a file:// to http:// request not working

Tags: go, header, server, cors, local

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4276931/4808079) about static to static (file:// -> file://) states that a webserver (http://) can be used to serve files to a local static page (file://) without violating CORS.  And [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8456586/4808079) states that when sending data from a webserver to a static page, a header of `null` must be used.  But neither of the two lines below are working, so how do I do it?

```
func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", nil) //this line
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hi there, I love %s!", r.URL.Path[1:])
}
```

returns the error `./main.go:42: cannot use nil as type string in argument to w.Header().Add`

```
func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "")
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hi there, I love %s!", r.URL.Path[1:])
}
```

This compiles but throws the client side error: `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/aardvark/posts. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After writing up this question, I thought to try one last thing out of desperation, and it worked.

```
func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "null")
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hi there, I love %s!", r.URL.Path[1:])
}
```

You're supposed to set the string to `"null"`, rather than a null string `""` or `nil`

If you don't think this question belongs on SO, please leave a comment and I'll promptly take it down.

Comment: Kudos! the implementations of NULL or absence of value are different among languages and platforms (i.e. JSON's is `null`, Python is `None`, Go is `nil`). For the HTTP Header, it's text-only format thus there is no way (and perhaps not desireable) for `nil` in Go to be converted to `null`.

Comment: Never allow the `null` origin, esp. with credentials. Doing so exposes your users to cross-origin attacks.