# How to set null authorization header in Go?

Tags: curl, go, https

I am writing a test suite for my program that fetches data from Github APIs. I need to set an empty authentication header. It works fine with `curl` but doesn't work in my Go program.

I tried setting it to "null" as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35966549/golang-setting-header-to-null-for-a-file-to-http-request-not-working). I've also tried `nil`, `""` which don't work.

The output (too long to copy here but you can try it yourself) is as expected with `curl -H "Authorization: " "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/issues?state=open&per_page=1&page=1"`

But here is the output with the same empty header set in Go:

`{"message":"Bad credentials","documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/v3"}`

Here is the code (please don't suggest that I just remove the `req.Header.Set()` line. I need to keep it in for my test suite)

```
func main() {

        client := &http.Client{}

        //issues API from Github
        req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/issues?state=open&per_page=1&page=1", nil)
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }   

        //set authorization header. I have tried nil, and ""
        req.Header.Set("Authorization", "null")

        resp, err := client.Do(req)
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }   

        defer resp.Body.Close()

        //convert to a usable slice of bytes
        body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
        if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("couldn't read issues list", err)
        }   

        fmt.Println(string(body))
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `curl` command does not set an empty `Authorization` header; that `curl` command *will exclude the `Authorization` header*. You can verify it by adding the `-v` parameter:

```
curl -H "Authorization: " -v "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/issues?state=open&per_page=1&page=1"
```

That being said, you shouldn't set `Authorization` header in your Go code either. So just remove that line, and your code becomes working immediately.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about curl. I need to keep that line in my Go code because I need to pass in multiple tokens for my tests. But given what you said, I think I will just write a condition to exclude setting the header if I have no token. Thanks I will accept your answer shortly.