# Firefox and Local Files

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

Is there way to access local files not in the current directory on Firefox?

I've done this

> about:config -> security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy to false

from a comment in [jQuery's .getJSON using local files stopped working on Firefox 3.6.13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699370/jquerys-getjson-using-local-files-stopped-working-on-firefox-3-6-13/4699386#4699386).

It's especially noticeable when I use jQuery.getScript() and call a file from a subdirectory or the parent directory.It says it's loaded but doesn't do anything with it, it appears.

Comment: Do you really *need* to do this? If you're developing a web application, why not install a web server?

Comment: It's for testing, so yes I need this. And since I'm a programmer I'm lazy :P But I'll take what you say into consideration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there way to access local files not in the current directory on Firefox?

Yes, you set `security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy` to `false`. If you've done it already then your problem is caused by something else and you need to ask a different question (preferably with some code). I tested it with the following HTML file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery.getScript("file:///.../test.js", function(data, status){
    alert(status + ":\n\n" + data + "\n\n" + window.a);
  });
</script>
```

With `test.js` being:

```
alert("Test succeeded");
var a = 1;
```

With `security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy` set to `true` nothing happens (not even a message in the Error Console). Once it is set to `false` I see the message `"Test succeeded"` and then another message saying `success: alert("Test succeeded");`. As one would expect.

That's Firefox 6.0.1 on Windows 7 x64. **Edit**: It's the same with Firefox 3.6.21.

Comment: Does the variables, functions created in test.js accessable. I know it loads as I have tested in the console, but for some reason my `window.object` is not there. (Which has been declared as a var)

Comment: @NebulaFox: I edited my example code to test for global variables as well. And it still works fine.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that I'm using jQuery-1.6.1 rather that 1.6.2.

Comment: @Joe: No, this setting never was accessible via anything other than about:config. It's an advanced setting that users should normally not mess with.