# how to load the local JSON variable using jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a local JSON dataset. I want to use jquery datatable plugin to display it. Is there any setting or configuration inside datatable plugin to display data? All I can find is to make AJAX calls and server calls.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I would also like to initialize with a local array of objects passed into aaData. I see that know one understood your question. I tried it with mData properties the way you would with a server side dataset but it didn't work.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can supply DataTables with data 4 different ways

- [DOM](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/dom.html)
- [Javascript array](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/js_array.html)
- [Ajax source](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/ajax.html)
- [Server side processing](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/server_side.html)

In your situation, you will want to use the second (Javascript Array) option. You will need to be able to translate the shape of your JSON object into an array objects.

Here's an example

```
var json = {
  BrowserStats : [
    { engine: "Trident", browser: "IE 4.0", platform: "Win 95+", version: 4 },
    { engine: "Trident", browser: "IE 5.0", platform: "Win 95+", version: 5 },
    { engine: "Trident", browser: "IE 5.5", platform: "Win 95+", version: 5.5 }
  ]
};

var data = jQuery.map(json.BrowserStats, function(el, i) {
  return new [el.engine, el.browser, el.platform, el.version];
});

$('#example').dataTable( {
  "aaData": data,
  "aoColumns": [
    { "sTitle": "Engine" },
    { "sTitle": "Browser" },
    { "sTitle": "Platform" },
    { "sTitle": "Version"}
  ]
});
```

Comment: I think the equals sign after BrowserStats should be a colon and you prob should delete the trailing comma after the third row.  Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Sample code in this answer doesn't work, see [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uvg3qre1/2/).

Comment: @JigarParekh This answer is almost 6 years ago, the DataTables API has likely changed. Feel free to edit this answer if you find the correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can get your json local file doing a normal ajax call, with some caveats (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy, or [jQuery's .getJSON using local files stopped working on Firefox 3.6.13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699370/jquerys-getjson-using-local-files-stopped-working-on-firefox-3-6-13), fwiw)

But it should definitely be possible to do:

```
$.getJSON('page.json', function(data) {
    /* do something with each item in data */
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the AjaxSource parameter that points to your DataSet:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "sAjaxSource": 'dataset.json'
} );
```

This will load all data once and place them into the DataTable. See more details on the http://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html.

Jovan

Answer (score 1):

Solving the problem with the [jessegavin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5651/jessegavin) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7640438/2668380):

```
$(document).ready(function (){

var json = {
  BrowserStats : [
    { engine: "Trident", browser: "IE 4.0", platform: "Win 95+", version: 4 },
    { engine: "Trident", browser: "IE 5.0", platform: "Win 95+", version: 5 },
    { engine: "Trident", browser: "IE 5.5", platform: "Win 95+", version: 5.5 }
  ]
};

var data = jQuery.map(json.BrowserStats, function(el, i) {
  return [[el.engine, el.browser, el.platform, el.version]];
});

$('#example').dataTable( {
  "aaData": data,
  "aoColumns": [
    { "sTitle": "Engine" },
    { "sTitle": "Browser" },
    { "sTitle": "Platform" },
    { "sTitle": "Version"}
  ]
 });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/byejn8ye/

Comment: Very helpful solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`data`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/data) option to supply data for a table.

For example:

```js
var table_data = [
    [ "Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "$3,120", "2011/04/25", "Edinburgh", 5421 ],
    [ "Garrett Winters", "Director", "$8,422", "2011/07/25", "Edinburgh", 8422 ]
];

$('#example').DataTable( {
    data: table_data
} );
```

If your data is a string in JSON format, you may want to parse it first with either [`$.parseJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/) or [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mgzh5a69/34/) for code and demonstration.