# jQuery Datatables with Stored Procedure

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am trying the jQuery datatables and its pretty amazing. What I need to do however is get data from a stored procedure (SQL Server 2012) which accepts a parameter. What are the options here? Do I have to build a web service to get the data or is it possible without creating a service layer?

Also I am unable to find an example that uses SP with parameters? If anyone has an example please share it with me.

Comment: Do I have to build a web service to get the data - Probably, you can't access the DB directly from the client/browser

Comment: So how do I pass the parameters to the webservice from AJAX? A querystring parameter for example?

Comment: Not sure I understand, but basically you pass the parameters from the table (filters/sorting/etc...) to your server using ajax, and on the server you perform the DB query with the relevant parameters and then you pass then back to the client. Check [this page](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/) and [this](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/) for relevant examples

Answer (score 1):

No, a web service is not obligatory.
Refer:
[Web service vs Direct connection to DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142070/why-should-a-developer-use-web-services-instead-of-direct-connections-to-a-db)

If you have control over the SQL server, options of using the JSON/CSV format as acceptable to data-tables is always there. Check [Data Sources for Datatables](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/).

Avoid cross-origin error while trying to access local files (maintain directory structure i.e. parent/origin/target file paths). Refer [Cross origins and local file access by Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699370/jquerys-getjson-using-local-files-stopped-working-on-firefox-3-6-13)

Hope some of it helps