# trouble reading json data using jquery

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jquery

I'm sure this is a silly oversight but I can't figure out how to get jQuery's 'getJSON' function to work. For test purposes, I have a directory set up as follows:

```
test.html
js/
  jquery-1.6.2.min.js
  test.js
ajax/
  test.json
```

and in the `<head>` of `test.html` I have the lines

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/test.js"></script>
```

As a first test of the `getJSON` function, `test.js` reads as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON('ajax/test.json', function(data) {
        alert('Success!');
    });
}
```

However, nothing happens when the 'test.html' is loaded. I have a feeling the 'ajax/test.json' path specification is the problem, but I'm not sure why.

EDIT: My bad on the curly brace, that was actually fine in the code I just mis-copy-pasted. I opened Chrome Developer Tools and now see an XMLHttpRequest error with the explanation: "Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin".

EDIT 2: Well that's annoying.. looks like it's a [Chrome issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541949/problems-with-jquery-getjson-using-local-files-in-chrome). Works fine on Safari. As a workaround you can fire up `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` in the base directory and access the page at localhost:8000/test.html, in which case Chrome works fine.

Comment: Open up Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools or whatever equivalent you have for your browser. Look at the Net tab to see if you are getting 404s. Look at the console to see if you have JS errors.

Comment: thanks.. i just did and it looks like there's an XMLHttpRequest error with the explanation: "Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin". what does this mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to run this directly from a file system. Make the pages available over HTTP (by installing a web server) and use that instead.

Local webpages have lots of different security rules to HTTP webpages.

Answer (score 3):

You need to close your brackets correctly on the `getJSON` callback function and the `ready` function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON('ajax/test.json', function(data) {
        alert('Success!');
    });
});
```

Comment: Ahh, yes. You are right. I somehow didn't think about the fact that the JS might just be included in the HTML file at the root directory... editing now.

Comment: my b that was a typo in the original question.. i've updated now

Answer (score 1):

your code:

```
$.getJSON('ajax/test.json', function(data) {
   alert('Success!');
); // you missed a curly brace here. that may be a problem
```

CORRECT CODE:

```
$.getJSON('ajax/test.json', function(data) {
        alert('Success!');
});
```

Comment: my b that was a typo in the question