# iUI Ajax hyperlinks not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, ajax, iui

I am testing [iUI](http://code.google.com/p/iui/) for mobile web apps. Instead of putting all content into a single HTML page, I am using the Ajax hyperlink technique described by Joe Hewitt [here](http://joehewitt.com/blog/introducing_iui.php). However I cannot get this to work in Chrome, although Joe Hewitt's own Digg demo, which uses the same technique, seems to work correctly.

Here is the simplified source code:

main.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;"/>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="iui/iui.css" type="text/css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="iui/t/default/default-theme.css" type="text/css"/>
   <script type="application/x-javascript" src="iui/iui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
   <div class="toolbar">
      <h1 id="pageTitle"></h1>
      <a id="backButton" class="button" href="#"></a>
   </div>

   <ul id="main" title="Main" selected="true">
      <li><a href="screen1.html">Go to Screen #1</a></li>
      <li><a href="screen2.html">Go to Screen #2</a></li>
   </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

screen1.html:

```
<div class="panel" title="Screen 1">
<ul><li>Hello 1</li></ul>
</div>
```

screen2.html:

```
<div title="Screen 2">
Hello 2
</div>
```

This works fine on Firefox (minus styling issue in screen2.html) but the links do not work on Chrome.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like does not have anything to do with iUI, rather it is a Chrome issue that affects loading any local files via Ajax.

Here is another SO question related to this issue, this time showing up with JQuery:

- [Problems with jQuery getJSON using local files in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541949/problems-with-jquery-getjson-using-local-files-in-chrome)

The accepted answer includes a link to the bug in the Chromium bug tracker.

Answer (score 1):

The AJAX-based navigation used may need to be viewed on a web server to work in certain browsers. If you see an error message when you click a link, try a different browser. When I'm using jQuery Mobile, sometimes the Ajax hyperlink technique works, sometimes it doesn't. Although the same code works fine on Opera.