# Parse local JSON file with JavaScript in Webkit

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I am currently trying to parse a local JSON file on Webkit browsers and I am running into a couple issues.

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
request.open('Get', 'file:///abc/test.json', false); 
var test = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
```

This however doesn't seem to work in Webkit Browsers (I am only testing on Webkit Browsers such as Chromium on ubuntu).

Could someone please help me point out what I might be doing wrong?
Thank you in advance!

Edit: I noticed a bunch of responses indicate it isn't possible to use Ajax. Is there anything else I can use such as JQuery or do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that webkit doesn't allow ajax requests to file:///
So you have to use a http server which serves the site and the ajax response.

Comment: Any other suggestions? I realized that it isnt possible using Ajax, is there something else you would recommend to use to load up the JSON file with?

Comment: You can add the "json file" using the script tag (<script src="file.js">). In the Javascipt file you just write something like var data = "your json". Then you can use the data variable.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried launching chrome with `--allow-file-access-from-files` key?
Seems to be related with [Problems with jQuery getJSON using local files in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541949/problems-with-jquery-getjson-using-local-files-in-chrome) question and [Local files doesn't load with Ajax](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=40787&q=ajax%20local&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Pri%20Area%20Feature%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Modified%20Owner%20Mstone%20OS) bug report.

Comment: Any other suggestions? I realized that it isnt possible using Ajax, is there something else you would recommend to use to load up the JSON file with?