# jQuery load and get

Tags: jquery

I have this markup for my `index.html`

```
<html>
     <head>
         <title>Jquery Ajax</title>
         <script src="jquery.js"></script>
         <script>
             $(document).ready(function(){
             $('button').click(function() {
                 $('#result').load('ajax/about.html');
             });
             });
         </script>
     </head>

     <body>
         <button>Click me</button>
         <div id="result">Hel</div>
     </body>
</html>
```

and in my `about.html` I have a simple text. When I click the button nothing happens. 
Consider that I have used $.get, too. but it does not works. Can someone help?

Comment: Are there any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: Works fine http://jsfiddle.net/7grqz/2/ . Are you sure `jquery.js` exists? Check  your console.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///D:/design&develop/Test/jquery-ajax/ajax/about.html. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: Well, abide by the policy then. Put your HTML online!

Comment: You need a WAMP server !

Comment: Thanks for WAMP. tested it works. Thanks you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problems with jQuery getJSON using local files in Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541949/problems-with-jquery-getjson-using-local-files-in-chrome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your working locally you may have issues if your using chrome try firefox instead or launch chrome like this

Mac

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --allow-file-access-from-files
```

Windows

```
open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app --args --allow-file-access-from-files
```

If your docs are all online then make sure your both files are on the same domain

Also if your using php i think you can add this

```
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?>
```

but make sure you remove it before going live

Comment: No probs long as you stay in the same domain when you go online then all should be fine :) good luck