# Displaying JSON Data

Tags: jquery, json

I am really somewhat baffled:

I have the following JSON data in a file called:  data.json

```
{
   "locations": [
      {
         "title": "The Space Needle",
         "latitude": 47.619,
         "longitude": -122.348
      },
      {
         "title": "Albany",
         "latitude": 46,
         "longitude": -74
      }
   ]
}
```

When I use the following code to try and display the data I get nothing:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Another gone south</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("data.json",function(data){
        $.each(data.locations, function(i,location){
                content += '<p>' + location.title + '</p>';
                content += '<p>' + location.latitude + '</p>';
                content += '<p' + location.longitude + '</p>';
                content += '<br/>';
                alert('aler called');
                $(content).appendTo("#loc");
        });
    });   
});
/* ]]> */
</script>
</head>
<body>
        <div class="container">
                <div class="span-24">
                       <h2>Check out the following locations:</h2>
                                        <div id="loc">
                                        </div>
                </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First thing...do you know you are loading the actual JSON file?  What kind of errors show up in your debugging console? What Have You Tried?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your json is returned your loop seems fine <strike>the only thing you may need to do is parse your JSON result before using it</strike>:

I looked at this again after what `JayC` said, I had the JSON value added to my example to a string (d'oh), off course ones I made it an object the each worked perfectly fine.

See [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9HDJy/) with JSON object (not string)

Basically your code should work perfectly fine which means either the request generates an error or you just get nothing returned.

Check the debug-console in the browser any errors. In FF you can use FireBug or in Chrome and IE use the build-in ones.

Comment: Sorry, my point didn't get across.  `getJSON` should never have to require manual parsing.... *because it's assumed you get JSON*.  It parses for you.

Comment: @JayC: Thanks again for your comments, as you see in my edit I was being a plank and tested it with the string version of the JSON object. Ones I used an actual JSON object it worked fine so the issue must be related to the request itself,..maybe cross-domain or something like that, not sure, I think OP needs to check console output.... as you suggested originally :)

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild shot, what browser are you using ? Is it not Chrome ? Is it not working Firefox as well ?
Because I've tried it in Firefox and it works correctly, displays both data and alerts. In Chrome I get error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///PATH. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

After some digging I found out that it may be problem with chrome, you may need to run it with

> chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-file

You may also need to define variable 'content' (for chrome), such as:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    content = $(this).html();
    $.getJSON("data.json",function(data){
        $.each(data.locations, function(i,location){
                content += '<p>' + location.title + '</p>';
                content += '<p>' + location.latitude + '</p>';
                content += '<p' + location.longitude + '</p>';
                content += '<br/>';
               alert('aler called');
             $(content).appendTo("#loc");
        });
    });   
});
```

This way it is working for both Chrome and Firefox (at my computer). To sum it up:
It's seems to be problem with Chrome, and should work on external server.

[Chrome issue link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541949/problems-with-jquery-getjson-using-local-files-in-chrome)