# JQuery $.getJSON load local JSON file not working

Tags: jquery, json, getjson

My problem is very simple, I have a file with the name of new.json and I am trying to use JQuery to load and display the data. I have been writing JavaScript code:

```
$.getJSON("new.json", function(data){
        // I have placed alert here previously and realized it doesn't go into here
        $.each(data.streetCity, function(i,s){
            alert(s);
        });
    });
}
```

and the data in new.json looks as below:

```
{"streetCity":
    {
        "1":"Abergement-Clemenciat",
        "2":"Abergement-de-Varey",
        "3":"Amareins"
    }
};
```

Comment: Make sure that `new.json` is in the same directory as the file that is running the JS that makes the ajax request.  I'm pretty sure you don't want the `;` either.

Comment: if not running server on local machine, some browsers won't allow ajax without adjusting settings

Comment: Possible duplicate, if you're using Chrome: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541949/problems-with-jquery-getjson-using-local-files-in-chrome

Comment: the interesting part is that it doesn't effect only Chrome but other browsers as well

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are using Chrome. Because Chrome don't allow xmlhttprequest to request local file. So jquery can not load your new.json

you can add

--allow-file-access-from-files

to the start command of chrome.  This can allow xmlhttprequest to load local resource

Comment: I was doing another application and reminds me for the issue. I have tried and yes it's working now, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using jQuery 1.5+ you can chain an error handler onto the call to see what is going on:

```
$.getJSON("new.json", function(data){
        // I have placed alert here previously and realized it doesn't go into here
        $.each(data.streetCity, function(i,s){
            alert(s);
        });
    }).error(function(jqXhr, textStatus, error) {
                alert("ERROR: " + textStatus + ", " + error);
    });
```

new.json is probably in a different path than the calling page. Also, if your snippets are accurate you don't need that last curly brace in the script or the last semicolon in the json.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the ';' (semicolon)  in the JSON file. JSON response doesn't need a semicolon. Remove that your example should work fine!