# Is there an option to enable json-loading from HDD in Chrome or Internet Explorer?

Tags: json, security, google-chrome, internet-explorer, file-io

Is there an option to enable Chrome or the Internet Explorer to load (via ajax-get) an JSON file from the local harddisk?

Firefox does so by default. Internet Explorer says 'premission denied' at the line

```
request.open(method, url, true);
```

Comment: Have you seen this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13871625/jquery-getjson-load-local-json-file-not-working ?

Comment: Added an answer to the post flagged by ZuoLi

Answer (score 1):

There are **no** simple cleaner way you can do this, you **have to do some server-side coding**.

I suggest you **node.js** this is very handy for this type of **IO** operations.

It looks very difficult for first time but it is very handy.

1. [Download](http://nodejs.org/download/) and install nodejs.
2. create a simple project to handle this.

   In the directory you want files to get (e.x. D:\myfiles), create one file `server.js`, content of that js file would be following

> ```
> var connect = require('connect');
> var serveStatic = require('serve-static');
> connect().use(serveStatic("./")).listen(105);
> ```

1. open command promp from and get to this directory (D:\myfiles)
2. Run these two commands `npm install connect` and `npm install serve-static` (up to this, is one time process)
3. Run `node server.js` - *That's all your server is ready and running*
4. call `http://localhost:105/<file name>` and you can get any files within that directory.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. In my specific case I have a C programm which gernerates me data and writes them into a json file. The html site plots the data with d3js. For this your suggestion has a huge overhead. Therefore it would be simpler to generate a javascript file.

Answer (score -1):

For chrome you can use following command line flags, taken from following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19902538/loading-local-files-with-javascript-without-a-web-server)

- --allow-file-access-from-files
- --disable-web-security

As noted in that question you need to restart your all chrome browsers.

For internet explorer, trick is to use ActiveX version of the XMLHttpRequest object.
See following link.

- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/9ae077e0-a7b9-433f-835f-2643aa1a7e09/ie11previewcannot-read-local-files-with-ajax-method-of-jquery?forum=iewebdevelopment