# getJSON not working, probably because of mime type

Tags: jquery, json, mime-types

I called an external JSON file and it worked as expected, but when I downloaded the file and called it locally, it didn't work. I guess it has something to do with application/json mime type not set in case of the local file. How can I set the mime type?

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data) { //works
$.getJSON(local, function(data) { //doesn't
```

Comment: add your serverside code script then  only we can get idea

Comment: "it didn't work" - could you elaborate?

Comment: Are you running something like: `$.getJSON("C:\temp\file.json", ...` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11297219/jquery-getjson-reading-a-local-file

Comment: to load a JSON file locally you need have a local web server, like `grunt-connect` or `lite-server`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13871625/jquery-getjson-load-local-json-file-not-working

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=getjson+local+file