# HTML5 WebApp - "Cannot make any requests from null" using jQuery ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, jquery

I have an HTML5 webapp and an API.

The webapp only pulls data from the API on startup.  After a period of time though, the data may become stale so I am having the webapp refresh after X minutes of inactivity.

The only problem with this is that if the API is down, the refresh will fail and the user will be shown an error page.  I would like to avoid this since usage of the webapp should be allowed even if the data is stale.

So when the refresh timeout expires, it should first check to see if the API is up before doing a refresh, otherwise reset the timer and try again in X minutes.

```
function refresh(reloadUrl) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'head',
    url: window.config.HOST_DOMAIN,
    success: function () {
      window.location = reloadUrl;
    },
    error: function (jqXHR) {
      console.log("Tried to refresh client, but API is unavailable (Error: " + jqXHR.status + ", URL: " + window.config.HOST_DOMAIN + ")");
      clearTimeout(window.IDLE_POWER_OFF);
        window.IDLE_POWER_OFF = window.setTimeout(window.client.navigation.splash.reload, window.IDLE_TIMEOUT);
    }
  });
}
```

However, when I try this I always get into the error callback, and the following in my console log:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://mydomain.com/api/whatever. Cannot make any requests from null.
Tried to refresh client, but API is unavailable (Error: 0, URL: http://mydomain.com/api/whatever)
```

Tried to search for the error "Cannot make any requests from null" but it only turned up stuff about iOS issues.  Anyone know what this error means?

Comment: Can you see anything in the network inspector? Also why does your example output say `UMR is unavailable` when the code says `URL is unavailable`.

Comment: Tried to replace UMR with API for the example but I missed a spot.  UMR is the name of my API.

Answer (score 0):

You don't state what browser, but is this because you are using a file:// url in the HTML document that you are working with?

See:  [Problems with jQuery getJSON using local files in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541949/problems-with-jquery-getjson-using-local-files-in-chrome)

Comment: SO, your easy solution is run a local websever. :)

Comment: or, use Firefox or a browser that allows AJAX from file:// (Safari is Webkit, so same error there)

Comment: Not using file scheme.  Browser is Chrome, and I am running a local web server for both client and server on different ports.  API route I'm hitting supposed to server json.

Comment: Just to make sure, the URL your browser is what?  (does it start with `http://localhost` or `file://` )