# Chrome Could not read external xml file using Jquery on local machine. but works fine when deployed on server

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

Chrome Could not read external XML file using jQuery on local machine. But works fine when deployed on server. I Know that using `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` option we can read external file in Chrome. But without using it how does it works in server?

Comment: The prevention of loading/including files on a local machine is a security feature of most browsers. Receiving a response from a 3rd party location removes this security barrier.

Comment: You could use a local server to sidestep this issue...IIS, Apache, etc., etc. See duplicate below for other ways around it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problems with jQuery getJSON using local files in Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541949/problems-with-jquery-getjson-using-local-files-in-chrome)