# Trying to load local JSON file to show data in a html page using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Hi I am trying to load local JSON file using JQuery to show data but i am getting some weird error. May i know how to solve this.

```
<html>
 <head>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>        

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
    $.getJSON( "priorities.json" , function( result ){
        alert(result.start.count);
    });
});
</script></head>
</html>
```

I am just alerting the count of JSON data. My JSON file is in the same directory where this html file is and JSON string format is shown below.

```
{
"start": {
    "count": "5",
    "title": "start",
    "priorities": [
        {
            "txt": "Work"
        },
        {
            "txt": "Time Sense"
        },
        {
            "txt": "Dicipline"
        },
        {
            "txt": "Confidence"
        },
        {
            "txt": "CrossFunctional"
        }
    ]
}
}
```

JSON file name priorities.json and error is

> Uncaught Referenceerror priorities is not defined

Comment: Check your HTML markup for unclosed tags somewhere. Is the `head` missing or you just forgot to copy and paste this part of the page?

Comment: I will parse but first before parsing only it is giving me error.

Comment: [Chrome will not like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541949/problems-with-jquery-getjson-using-local-files-in-chrome).

Comment: You error says that you are trying to use an undefined var/object called `priorities` that doesn't exist and/or is undefined. That code isn't responsible for the error, I think.

Comment: Joum there is no undefined variable

Comment: I know that error  and i am verifying it in server also> It's giving me same error

Comment: Are you loading file from your local hard disk?

Comment: yeah i am loading from hard disk  and html and json file both are in same directory

Comment: how to resolve it without GET /POST requests

Comment: @Venkat: declare it like `var json = yourjson;` and use a script tag to load it.

Comment: Or include it directly to your page.

Comment: including how to do that

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As the jQuery API says: "Load JSON-encoded data from the server using a GET HTTP request."

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

So you cannot load a local file with that function. But as you browse the web then you will see that loading a file from filesystem is really difficult in javascript as the following thread says:

[Local file access with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371875/local-file-access-with-javascript)

Comment: Actually I managed it with my browser - http://qtweb.net/. and I think it is also feasible in Chrome (for example) if you enable an option when you run it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819060/allow-google-chrome-to-use-xmlhttprequest-to-load-a-url-from-a-local-file .

Comment: yeah that works with chrome, but I would consider that more of a hack than a final solution..

Answer (score 47):

You can simply include a Javascript file in your HTML that declares your JSON object as a variable. Then you can access your JSON data from your global Javascript scope using `data.employees`, for example.

index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="data.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

data.js:

```
var data = {
  "start": {
    "count": "5",
    "title": "start",
    "priorities": [{
      "txt": "Work"
    }, {
      "txt": "Time Sense"
    }, {
      "txt": "Dicipline"
    }, {
      "txt": "Confidence"
    }, {
      "txt": "CrossFunctional"
    }]
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you know of any way to display that from the html script? isnt it just console.log(data)?

Comment: Ya the code in data.js is globally available from the HTML document, so using `data` or `data.start.count` within a `<script>` element in your HTML will work.

Comment: This is also a JavaScript not a Json-Solution! :(

Comment: It returns empty file, should I write absolute path for the `data.js`, which also does not work ? @senornestor

Comment: Yeah, for offline data testing this is best! :) I was thinking of it while reading all answers above :p

Answer (score 40):

Due to security issues (same origin policy), javascript access to local files is restricted if **without user interaction**.

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Same-origin_policy_for_file:_URIs:

> A file can read another file only if the parent directory of the
>   originating file is an ancestor directory of the target file.

Imagine a situation when javascript from a website tries to steal your files **anywhere in your system without you being aware of**. You have to deploy it to a web server. Or try to load it with a script tag. Like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>        
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="priorities.json"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(e) {
         alert(jsonObject.start.count);
   });
</script>
```

Your priorities.json file:

```
var jsonObject = {
"start": {
    "count": "5",
    "title": "start",
    "priorities": [
        {
            "txt": "Work"
        },
        {
            "txt": "Time Sense"
        },
        {
            "txt": "Dicipline"
        },
        {
            "txt": "Confidence"
        },
        {
            "txt": "CrossFunctional"
        }
    ]
}
}
```

Or declare a callback function on your page and wrap it like jsonp technique:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js">    </script> 
     <script type="text/javascript">
           $(document).ready(function(e) {

           });

           function jsonCallback(jsonObject){
               alert(jsonObject.start.count);
           }
        </script>

 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="priorities.json"></script>
```

Your priorities.json file:

```
jsonCallback({
    "start": {
        "count": "5",
        "title": "start",
        "priorities": [
            {
                "txt": "Work"
            },
            {
                "txt": "Time Sense"
            },
            {
                "txt": "Dicipline"
            },
            {
                "txt": "Confidence"
            },
            {
                "txt": "CrossFunctional"
            }
        ]
    }
    })
```

Using script tag is a similar technique to JSONP, but with this approach it's not so flexible. I recommend deploying it on a web server.

With user interaction, javascript is allowed access to files. That's the case of [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/). Using file api, javascript can access files **selected by the user** from `<input type="file"/>` or dropped from the desktop to the browser.

Comment: This is a nice little hack

Comment: In this "solution" `priorities.json` is not a JSON file anymore, but a JavaScript file.

Comment: Do you have html file for this as well where I can try to run? @Khanh TO

Comment: @alper, I don't, but you can easily create one

Comment: This is not good, I currently am trying to fix a CSP issue, and just calling a json file a javascript file does nobody no good ) :

Comment: @Derrops: could you be more specific about your problem of trying to fix a CSP issue? This question is just about loading a local json file, maybe the author of the question needed a way to quickly do some UI development locally (with data). In QA and production environments, we should deploy to real servers.

Comment: All good your answer is an ok work around but it does not answer the question. If you make a json file a javascript file it is no longer content but becomes a script. This can be a security issue, imagine if that file was uploaded by the user, or retrieved from a service somewhere, that could lead to xss vulnerability. Also some restricting CSPs (Content Security Policies) could block your script from running altogether.

Comment: @Derrops: i believe when we deploy the code to PROD, we have to load the json properly. Besides, this was a technique called JSONP in the past to load json from another domain when CORS was not very supported, it also relies on trust with the other domain

Answer (score 4):

**app.js**

```
$("button").click( function() {
 $.getJSON( "article.json", function(obj) {
  $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
         $("ul").append("<li>"+value.name+"'s age is : "+value.age+"</li>");
  });
 });
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Tax Calulator</title>
    <script src="jquery-3.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul></ul>
    <button>Users</button>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**article.json**

```
{
"a": {
"name": "Abra",
"age": 125,
"company": "Dabra"
},
"b": {
"name": "Tudak tudak",
"age": 228,
"company": "Dhidak dhidak"
}
}
```

**server.js**

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

function onRequest(request,response){
  if(request.method == 'GET' && request.url == '/') {
          response.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type":"text/html"});
          fs.createReadStream("./index.html").pipe(response);
  } else if(request.method == 'GET' && request.url == '/jquery-3.2.0.min.js') {
          response.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type":"text/javascript"});
          fs.createReadStream("./jquery-3.2.0.min.js").pipe(response);
  } else if(request.method == 'GET' && request.url == '/app.js') {
          response.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type":"text/javascript"});
          fs.createReadStream("./app.js").pipe(response);
  }
  else if(request.method == 'GET' && request.url == '/article.json') {
          response.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type":"text/json"});
          fs.createReadStream("./article.json").pipe(response);
  }
}

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(2341);
console.log("Server is running ....");
```

Server.js will run a simple node http server in your local to process the data.

**Note** don't forget toa dd jQuery library in your folder structure and change the version number accordingly in **server.js** and **index.html**

This is my running one https://github.com/surya4/jquery-json.

Answer (score 3):

The d3.js visualization examples I've been replicating on my local machine.. which import .JSON data.. all work fine on Mozilla Firefox browser; and on Chrome I get the cross-origins restrictions error.
It's a weird thing how there's no issue with importing a local javascript file, but try loading a JSON and the browser gets nervous. There should at least be some setting to let the user over-ride it, the way pop-ups are blocked but I get to see an indication and a choice to unblock them.. no reason to be so Orwellian about the matter. Users shouldn't be treated as too naive to know what's best for them.

So I suggest using Firefox browser if you're working locally. And I hope people don't freak out over this and start bombing Mozilla to enforce cross-origin restrictions for *local files*.

Answer (score -3):

I would try to save my object as .txt file and then fetch it like this:

```
 $.get('yourJsonFileAsString.txt', function(data) {
   console.log( $.parseJSON( data ) );
 });
```

Comment: This has the exact same problem as getJSON.

Answer (score -3):

I have Used Following Methods But non of them worked:

```
   // 2 Method Failed

        $.get(
            'http://www.corsproxy.com/' +
            'en.github.com/FEND16/movie-json-data/blob/master/json/movies-coming-soon.json',
            function (response) {
                console.log("> ", response);
                $("#viewer").html(response);
            });
// 3 Method Failed

    var jqxhr = $.getJSON( "./json/movies-coming-soon.json", function() {
  console.log( "success" );
})
  .done(function() {
    console.log( "second success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    console.log( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    console.log( "complete" );
  });

// Perform other work here ...

// Set another completion function for the request above
jqxhr.always(function() {
  console.log( "second complete" );
});

// 4 Method Failed

$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   crossDomain: true,
   dataType: 'jsonp',
   url: 'https://github.com/FEND16/movie-json-data/blob/master/json/movies-coming-soon.json',
   success: function(jsondata){
    console.log(jsondata)
   }
})

// 5 Method Failed


$.ajax({
   url: 'https://github.com/FEND16/movie-json-data/blob/master/json/movies-coming-soon.json',
   headers: {  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'htt://site allowed to access' },
   dataType: 'jsonp',
   /* etc */
   success: function(jsondata){

   }
})
```

What worked For me to simply download chrome extension called "200 OK!" or Web server for chrome and write my code like this:

```
// Worked After local Web Server

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.getJSON('./json/movies-coming-soon.json', function (data) {
              var movie_name = '';
              var movie_year = '';
                $.each(data,function(i,item){
                    console.log(item.title,item.year,item.poster)
                    movie_name += item.title + "  " + item.year + "<br> <br>"

                    $('#movie_name').html(movie_name)


                })

            })

        })
```

Its because you can not access local file without running local web server as per CORS policy so in order to running it you must have some host server.