# How to load, and save local JSON into variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am very new to this, trying to follow http://javascriptissexy.com/how-to-learn-javascript-properly/ by making a quiz, any additional advice is welcome. I put the JSON file at the bottom of js as comment.

http://jsfiddle.net/Atlas_/Mgyc5/

Supposed to be the holy grail ? :I

```
var theQuiz;
$.getJSON("package.json", function (json) {
    theQuiz = json;
});
```

Comment: install firebug for firefox open the console tab and see what error you are getting

Comment: eathier run your code on a server (exp :wamp local server) or do what @rajesh said

Answer (score 2):

Thanks guys, i figured it out by checking and rechecking the dev console, but mostly staring at the monitor in disbelief. I actually need help now to get it to work with a server tried few including a local one and no luck.

Valuable Lesson

```
$.getJSON("package.json", /*loads, if in the same folder*/ function (json) {
theQuiz = json.quiz; // Had to make sure to pick out the array because JSON put it into an extra object
console.log(theQuiz); // object Array
console.log(json);  // object Object
console.log(theQuiz[0].question); // Works! "How many times your heart beats in a day?(choose the closest)"
// but it's not working because js doesn't wait for JSON to load and it starts using the variables that doesn't exist yet
});
```

Solution

```
$.ajax({
dataType: "json",
async: false, // Makes sure to wait for load
url: "package.json", //  https://www.dropbox.com/s/fmw63i4v7dtnx6t/package.json
'success': function (json) {
    theQuiz = json.quiz;
    console.log(json);  // object Object
    console.log(theQuiz); // object Array
    // Finishes loading before js starts using it, and works as intended
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

JSON FILE[json.js]

```
 var country = {name:"india",code:"IND"};
```

HTML FILE

```
// adding file in script
<script src="json.js"></script>

//using json in script
<script>
  country.name // will give india
</script>
```

Comment: This is wrong, country is becoming a global variable. The file is not a json ... does not answer the actual question it's a dirty work around.

Comment: The example of JSON FILE is not valid JSON.

Answer (score -1):

Using getJSON you can load JSON-encoded data from the server using a GET HTTP request. you cannot load a local file with that function. You can load local file but that is not very easy. Check the below link.

[Local file access with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371875/local-file-access-with-javascript)

Also please check

[Trying to load local JSON file to show data in a html page using JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18637418/trying-to-load-local-json-file-to-show-data-in-a-html-page-using-jquery)

Comment: if package.json is in the same folder as the html file this is a valid request(relative path)

Comment: @Exlord - If you check http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/. JQuery document tation says "JSON-encoded data from the server". This does not at all talk about the relative path. Let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: ok you could be right i just assumed that he is running the file on a server if he is opening the html file directly then yes getJson dosn't even run