# Trouble accessing JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm having some trouble accessing my JSON data with an AJAX call.

JSON

```
{
    "Ongoing": [
        {"name": "meh"},
        {"name": "hem"}
    ],
    "Completed": [
        {"name": "kfg"},
        {"name": "dkfgd"}
    ]
}
```

JS

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "script/projects.json",
    complete: function(data){
        for(var i = 0; i < data.Ongoing.length; i++){
            console.log(data.Ongoing[i].name);
        }

    }
})
```

When I write to the console, I getting the following error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

So for some reason it's kicking back that the array is undefined.

I've passed the JSON into the validator, so I know it's valid JSON.  I know that jQuery's `$.ajax` parses JSON automatically.  So I'm confused, I should be able to access the data like a normal object.  Can anyone explain to me what I've done wrong and provide an explanation to how to fix it?

The following image shows what simply writing `data` to the console displays.
[image]

Comment: Can you do a console log of just `data` to see what it contains?

Comment: Sure thing.  I'll add a screenshot to the question to show what writing just data shows.

Comment: can't do this using `file://` see my answer

Comment: @Robert is that JSON being returned in fiddler ?

Comment: @Robert Can you tell us what you get with `console.log(data)` ?

Comment: @huggilou, the image in the question shows what the console returns when writing `data`.  I believe I have the problem figured out though.  If I work inside the `success` function, I'm able to access the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must load the file through a web server, you are loading it using `file://` you can however override this in Chrome using  the`--allow-file-access-from-files` flag

see: [Trying to load local JSON file to show data in a html page using JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18637418/trying-to-load-local-json-file-to-show-data-in-a-html-page-using-jquery)

Comment: Forgot I needed to be doing this within a server.  I'm still not able to access the data though.  I'll update the question.

Comment: does `projects.json` exist in the same directory as the page?

Comment: Yes it does and I noticed that the path was wrong so I fixed it as well.

Comment: what is the result return in the network when the ajax request is sent?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean the `success` function?  If I do a console log in that to print 'hi' it does so.  so I know that the file is being loaded.

Comment: no under, the network tab in the inspector a new entry will be made when ajax is called. that should tell you if the file loads or not.

Comment: Oh.  The network tab is showing that the file is there and that it has a status of 304

Comment: Now, if I work inside the `success` function instead of the `complete` function, I actually get everything successfully.  Should I be working inside of that function instead of `complete`?

Comment: Ok, then that was the problem.  Thanks for all the help, I'm accepting your answer since it led to the actual solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Ongoing`is an array, so you have first to access at an element :

```
console.log(data.Ongoing[0].name);
```

Comment: This is correct but the TypeError is hitting `data.Ongoing` so he's not even getting that far.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Ongoing` property contains an array

`"Ongoing": [
        {"name": "meh"},
        {"name": "hem"}
    ]`

To access one you can do it by looping

```
$.each(data.Ongoing, function(index, value) {
   console.log(value.name);
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't simply doing a for loop accomplish the same thing?

Comment: @Robert yeah you could do it on a for loop also

Answer (score 0):

The code is good. Your problem is in the request. Check the url

Comment: can add the request response?