# viewer.js invoking 'fail' event in Android WebView

Tags: html, android-webview, box-view-api

I'm currently trying to make the HTML5 [viewer.js example](http://developers.box.com/viewer-js/) work inside an android WebView.

WebView initialization looks like this:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
final WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

The thing is that in a Nexus 7 running Android 4.3 JB (which uses Chrome as stock browser) the example fails and renders: ***Error loading document metadata (did you check the url?)***. I also tried a Samsung Galaxy Nexus running 4.2 with same results.

But on a GBox (MediaBox, Android TV) running Android 4.0.4 ICS (which uses the default Browser application), it takes a while but it renders the document. With a lot of styles problems, but it can render it.

However, if I serve all the assets from a remote server (for instance, a Python SimpleHttpServer) and load the WebView using the index page url, it doesn't have any problems in any device.

Is this a Crocodoc View API specific issue regarding cross-browsing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Chrome-specific issue, see here: [Problems with jQuery getJSON using local files in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541949/problems-with-jquery-getjson-using-local-files-in-chrome)

In summary, Chrome's security model blocks AJAX requests from `file:///` URLs. This causes trouble for viewer.js because it utilizes AJAX to load resources in a performance optimized manner. The recommended  solution is to always serve the assets through a web server.