# Load page fragments with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

So I have a menu:

```
<nav id="side-nav">
<ul>
<li><a href="consulting">Consulting</a></li>
etc..
```

jQuery reads

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $( "#side-nav ul li a" ).on( "click",function() {
   $('#services-content').load('side-menu.html #' + $(this).attr('href'));
    return false;
  });
});
```

and have an html file with corresponding id's to the href. It does not load. Thought i followed exactly as per jquery website. Whats wrong ?

Even if I have it hard coded, nothing is loaded :

```
<div id="services-content">

</div><!--load services content in here-->

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#services-content').load('side-menu.html #consulting');
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read [Local files doesn't load with Ajax in Chrome but Work on Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19841446/)

Are you working locally on your machine, without any webserver? Chrome does not allow loading files via AJAX from your file system (see [bugreport](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=40787&q=ajax%20local&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Pri%20Area%20Feature%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Modified%20Owner%20Mstone%20OS)).

You may use XAMPP or something similar to serve your files via a local webserver.

If you are on Windows, XAMPP is probably the easiest way to get your local webserver up and running: http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html

On Mac, you may also use MAMP http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html

You may also force Chrome to allow local file access on Windows if you are starting it with `--allow-file-access-from-files`, more information in [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541949/problems-with-jquery-getjson-using-local-files-in-chrome)

Comment: Nop, there has to be a space

Comment: @chucky you are correct you need that space.But why u use return false ?

Comment: Does it matter ? I just followed the example on [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: @chucky try running code without return false.and Check console for errors .

Comment: It attempts to open a URL- ie: 'consulting'. Does the side-menu file have to be in specific format?

Comment: @chucky just html which contains element with id `consulting` as you are calling that element in `.load()` .Is your site live ?

Comment: Nope its not live. Does it even have to be an href why not `a id="consulting"`

Comment: @chucky It's up to you .if you use than use `load('side-menu.html #' + $(this).attr('id'));` or `load('side-menu.html #' + this.id);`.But better is if you use `<a href="#consulting"`

Comment: @chucky check console for error and are you including jQuery library ?

Comment: Yes its included.  console- 'XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/IBC/side-menu.html.'

Comment: Works in firefox, i think i solved it. Tested only with Chrome, I think it does not like the file to be in a local directory. Probably wants it to be on a server...

Comment: Thanks for help, i spotted it same time :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a scope problem. I didn't test this, so don't shoot me.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $( "#side-nav ul li a" ).on( "click",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $this = $(this);
    $('#services-content').load('side-menu.html#' + $this.attr('href'));
  });
});
```