# How To Skip "Cross Origin Requests" Using JavaScript/JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, offline

I am trying to read a `.xml` file that is a feed using JavaScript/JQuery in my PC to show data on my browser. You can view my **[feed.xml](https://shrib.com/xMQBq7HOBOHqx1Y)** file online that I saved from **[GoogleBlogXMLFeed](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default/?redirect=false&max-results=500)**. When I tried to read it via following codes in my `index.html` file that is in same folder where `feed.xml` file is...

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $.ajax({
        url: "feed.xml",
        success: function(xml){ 
            var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
            $xml = $(xmlDoc),
            title = $xml.find("title").text();
            alert(title);
        }
    });
</script>
```

But on opening my file in Chrome, I am getting the below error.

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///D:/feed.xml Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.`

I am not using any SERVER/HOST like Wamp,IIS,Xamp etc. So is there any way to remove this error and read the file data as normal XML...???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  Chrome does not allow cross-origin requests for files loaded from the file system. See this question that has been asked before.

[Problems with jQuery getJSON using local files in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541949/problems-with-jquery-getjson-using-local-files-in-chrome)

Comment: Thanks, Firefox Is Showing This... :-)

Comment: You can also run in `Chrome` using command line argument `chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files`...