# Existing Jquery library on page not working for dynamic html content called by ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, dynamic

I am using this code to get dynamic html. But existing jquery library and event other functions or js code not working for this dynamic code.

```
function getDynamicContent(id, tab_id) {
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: "test.php",
                data: 'id=' + id,
                type: "POST",
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#' + tab_id).html(data);
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Errors in console? PHP errors??? Also Try `data: {id:id},`

Comment: No error in console, No php error. Called this function on click event. JS existing on same page is working but not for ajax call response html.

Comment: Click of what? If a button in a form, then you might submit the form before calling the Ajax. Post relevant HTML with event handlers

Comment: Actually i am getting page content by ajax call. By click on navigation menus.

Comment: Not enough information to help you.

Comment: @Navdeep - are you saying that, for instance, you have a click event bound to a particular class, which isn't working on elements loaded in via AJAX? If so, are you using _$(element).click(myfunction)_ or _$(element).on('click', myfunction)_?

Comment: PLease share more information

Comment: onclick event like: <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="getDynamicContent('data', "#div_id")">New Page</a>

Answer (score 0):

If you use chrome, Chrome doesn't like AJAX from local files.

This is a known issue with Chrome.

[Read this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2788067/7507686)